# Personalizing Trello invitation message

Tags: trello

I'm a member of an IRL ONG and I invited several to a Trello board. But as they don't know what's this "trello" they put their invitation in the trash.

Can I change the invitation message to write a personalized message?

Comment: What's an "ONG"? And don't worry about your English. It's better than I see from many native speakers.

Comment: oh sorry i use the french abbreviation : NGO (non governmental organisation) here only a student organization - I didn't want to complicate with the term "organisation" used in trello for a group of board...  _ @AlEverett thanks for my english ;-)

Comment: The problem here is that i don't know all the member personnally, so they put the invitation in the trash. I think that with an personnalized message it could be more understandable (and i could add a message in french too for people who don't understand well english)